# Retrieve file url in PHP, from an encoded string recieved from android

Tags: php, android, encoding, base64, decoding

I am capturing image in my Android application and saving the name of the image as "image_random_number.png". I am converting this file to bitmap , encoding the bitmap in base-64 and then sending it to API(PHP). In PHP i am decoding this string and storing it in server, which is working fine. now i want to get the file URL from this string being recieved.

```
String imageFileName = "image_random_number";
File file = new File(IMAGEPATH + "/" + imageFileName + ".png");
Bitmap bitmap = Lib.decodeFile(file, thisContext);
part_requested_image_1 = Lib.GetBitmapEncodedString(bitmap);
```

This is my code for Encoding the bitmap. How do i get back the file name or file url in PHP ?

Comment: The file name will still be image_random_number.png. So what is it what you are asking?

Comment: `i want to get the file URL from this string being recieved.` I think you would need a download url for your png file.

Comment: @blackapps I am not able to retrieve the image file name in PHP. That is what i am asking for.

Comment: I do not read that in your post. In your post you ask something different. Something that i did not understand too. If you do not sent the image name to php then how would php know it? Please rewrite your post to make it clear what you do and want.